# Swift - How to Pass Data From UITableViewCell Class to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I was wondering how to pass data from a class that extends from UITableViewCell to a view controller? I have some outlets on a custom cell connected to the UITableViewCell class that I would like to access from my UIViewController class.

Prepareforsegue only works for passing data between two viewcontrollers, so that does not apply to this case. All of the answers I have found on stack (and in various corners of the web) are in objective-c and no longer apply to swift. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the `UIViewController` inside the `UITableViewCell`. The `UIViewController` being references is usually called the `delegate`. Once you have the delegate set, you can call methods or access properties on it. There are lots of examples if you do an internet search.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the UITableViewCell from the UIViewController where it is displayed? If so, you should be able to access the outlets from your UITableViewCell using the dot operator.

```
// Example In UIViewController
let customCell = UITableViewCell()  // This is whatever your custom cell is

let objectFromCell = customCell.outlet
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It helped a lot. I have one more minor question though. When I wright:       
        let customCell = TableViewCell()
        
        let Title = customCell.titleLabel.text - an error comes up saying that xcode unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional on the Title variable line. Do you know why this could be (especially since titleLabel.text already has a value). Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your customCell is hooked up to the same UITableViewCell in the storyboard? If it is, it must be the you don't have text in the title label. Maybe the text is in the contentLabel instead? It would help to see a little bit of the code.